# Xcode: error: module file was created for incompatible target armv7-apple-ios8.0 (Alamofire & Cocoapods)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, watchkit, alamofire

I have an iOS app with Watchkit Extension and in the last version I've started using Cocoapods to manage better the dependencies. I've been leading with some errors trying to update to Swift 2.0 but everything was ok. Now I can build the project without problems and run it perfectly.

However when I try to archive the app with Watchkit Extension target to publish my app, I receive the following error:

```
error: module file was created for incompatible target armv7-apple-ios8.0: /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2B-dknnmkplfuhntmbjfxavlmufuiif/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/B2B/BuildProductsPath/Release-watchos/Pods-B2B WatchKit Extension/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/arm.swiftmodule
import Alamofire
       ^
```

I'm using the last version of Alamofire 3.0. Both the iOS app and the Watch app are using Alamofire to get data from internet. My Cocoapods file is this one:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!
link_with 'B2B', 'B2B WatchKit Extension'
link_with 'B2B', 'B2B Free'

def shared_all_pods  
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end

def shared_app_pods
  pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 0.95'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
end

target 'B2B' do
  shared_all_pods
  shared_app_pods
  pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 2.0'
end

target 'B2B Free' do
  shared_all_pods
  shared_app_pods
end

target 'B2B WatchKit Extension' do
  platform :watchos, '2.0'
  shared_all_pods
  pod 'MMWormhole', '~> 2.0'
end
```

Is anyone else having a similar error? What I'm doing wrong? Maybe my Cocoapod file isn't right? Or I shouldn't use Alamofire for Watchkit Extension?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I have the same error when building with Travis CI

Comment: Did you find a way to fix that?

Comment: i have this issue too. @j_gonfer did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @JoeDaniels I'm sorry guys but I wasn't able to fix this. At the end I made a new version from scratch because the project was totally messed up.